# Implement InCell and PopUp editing together

Tags: kendo-grid

Is any way how to do it?

I have grid for translations. It is in 90% of usage 1 or 2 words and InCell mode is ideal for it. But in several cases, it can be very long phrase and there woud be nice to have posibility use also PopUp edit in same grid.

Is any way how to implemented it together?

For now it seems that most reasonable solution is use InCell editing as default and popup make like some template.

Any other ideas or tutorials how to implement PopUp editing by own way - without set .Editable(ed=>ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp)?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ilIjI/3). In detail template you can add editors for some fields containing long string